# Trying to save 10 digit phone number, but it is throwing an invalid int error

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Basically, I have an edittext box that is limited to 10 numbers via xml. When i enter anything less than 7 it shows a toast. 7 integers saves the string as it should. 8 or 9 integers shows its appropriate toast. However, when i enter a full 10 digits, i get this error...

```
09-28 15:29:11.312: E/AndroidRuntime(19193): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could notexecute method of the activity
09-28 15:29:11.312: E/AndroidRuntime(19193):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3830)
09-28 15:29:11.312: E/AndroidRuntime(19193):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4445)
09-28 15:29:11.312: E/AndroidRuntime(19193):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18446)
09-28 15:29:11.312: E/AndroidRuntime(19193):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
09-28 15:29:11.312: E/AndroidRuntime(19193):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
09-28 15:29:11.312: E/AndroidRuntime(19193):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
09-28 15:29:11.312: E/AndroidRuntime(19193):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5140)
09-28 15:29:11.312: E/AndroidRuntime(19193):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-28 15:29:11.312: E/AndroidRuntime(19193):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
09-28 15:29:11.312: E/AndroidRuntime(19193):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:611)
09-28 15:29:11.312: E/AndroidRuntime(19193): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
09-28 15:29:11.312: E/AndroidRuntime(19193):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-28 15:29:11.312: E/AndroidRuntime(19193):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3825)
09-28 15:29:11.312: E/AndroidRuntime(19193):    ... 9 more
09-28 15:29:11.312: E/AndroidRuntime(19193): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "3557565542"
09-28 15:29:11.312: E/AndroidRuntime(19193):    at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:137)
09-28 15:29:11.312: E/AndroidRuntime(19193):    at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:377)
09-28 15:29:11.312: E/AndroidRuntime(19193):    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:365)
09-28 15:29:11.312: E/AndroidRuntime(19193):    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:331)
```

and the method...

```
 public void onOk(View src) {
        Product p = new Product();
        p.name = _name.getText().toString();
        p.number = Integer.parseInt(number.getText().toString());

        if ((number.getText().toString().trim().length() == 7)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter the full 10 digit phone number for best results",   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent result = new Intent();
        result.putExtra("product", p);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, result);
        finish();
        } 
        else if (number.getText().toString().trim().length() < 7) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter at least 7 digits",   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if ((number.getText().toString().trim().length() == 8) || number.getText().toString().trim().length() == 9)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You entered " + _price.getText().toString().trim().length() + ". Please enter a 10 digit phone number.",   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Intent result = new Intent();
            result.putExtra("product", p);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, result);
            finish();
        }
        }
```

I've tried everything I can think of and nothing solves it. I'm sure it's just something I have overlooked.

Comment: Can you try Integer.valueOf() instead of parse()?

Comment: changing it to Long solved the problem. I was using a number that was over the max value of an int.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The max value for an int in java is 2,147,483,647 when you enter anything above it your app crashes. Try using a long which has a max value of 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.

Also if you're saving a phone number I would recommend using a String unless you need to do math on the phone number (unlikely). Some phone numbers have characters like '+', '*', '#', etc.

Comment: Or use a `String` type, as you're not likely to do numerical manipulations with telephone numbers

Comment: I changed it to long and it works great. I can't believe I missed that. Thanks for the solution!

Comment: Again, please use a String for phone numbers.

Comment: A long worked, but I did change it to a string. When it was a long, I ran into an issue when I tried to check the ET box for 0. It threw the error that 0 was an invalid Long. I changed it to a string and it is working perfect. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

use double instead of int value